# asp.net master page, menu links, route registering

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have a Master page with the menu links. Each menu link is an HTML anchor with an HREF property set to an easily remembered/written URL, e.g. "main-page". Here is an example:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="menu">    
       <li><a href="main-page" class="parent">Main Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my Global.asax, under Application_Start, I register routes using the RouteCollection object as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("main-page", "main-page", "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

This works fine. Whenever I click on the Main Page menu link, it redirects me to Default.aspx. But I have one problem. One of the routes is defined like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("news-detail", "news-detail/{newsId}", "~/NewsDetail.aspx");
```

This means it accepts news Id as a parameter and redirects to NewsDetails.aspx page with the corresponding news Id. At this point the navigation bar looks like this:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/news-detail/21
```

Here "21" represents the Id of the news I am displaying. So if I click on the "Main Page" menu link to go the main page, it tries to take me to this location:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/news-detail/main-page
```

which is an invalid URL.

How can I define my menu links so that they will always take me to the right page even if I am in a nested page (in this case I am under "/news-detail/21")? I hope I could explain myself clear.

Comment: Is it not necessary to include "MyApp" in the routes? Or "MyApp" represents "~"?

Comment: Where have you defined the route to "NewsDetail.aspx"?

Comment: I do the manual redirect in my "News.aspx" page when the user clicks on the details link of a news. In my repeater where the "Details" linkbutton found, the PostBackUrl is set to PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("news-detail/{0}", Eval("Id")) %>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think your problem is the `href` attribute.

Try changing with the following:

```
<a href="~/main-page" class="parent">Main Page</a>
```

If this doesn't work, try to change the HTML anchor for an ASP.NET HyperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlMain" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/main-page" CssClass="parent" Text="MainPage" />
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Then, change your code as:

```
PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("~/news-detail/{0}", Eval("Id")) %>'
```

Comment: You are welcome. Mixing ASP.NET features with regular HTML sometimes take you to this kind of incomprehensible situations.

Comment: exactly. you put an anchor instead of an hyperlink thinking they are about the same. but the anchor is dumb and cannot redirect to "~/main-page" whereas the hyperlink can provide the right postback url with the same address. thank you once again.